# How to add rectangles one side to another at a different angle in THREE JS?

Tags: three.js

Is it possible to add in three js rectangles one side to another at a different angle? 30 degrees, 90 degrees etc.

I have attached an image.

Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmzOh.png)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But what have you tried? There are many approaches to do it.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with PlaneBufferGeometry to add the panels in a row and with  mesh.rotation.y I can rotate a panel, but it rotates it from the center of it. I would like to rotate it from the left side or right as you see attached in my design above. I don't know if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried applying translation? Are you familiar with the field of mathematics called "trigonometry"?

Comment: No, I know what trigonometry is, but I don't know how to apply it. Do you have some refference where I can read more about it or can you help me with 2 rendedered sides at an angle and I could learn from that and continue my learning path?. Thank you